# Is it possible to change the typography style of a material-ui TextField component to use a caption variant?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to learn material-ui for use within a Typescript React environment. I am using the following fragment within a `Dialog`:

```js
...
<React.Fragment>
    <Typography variant="body1">
    <Box mt={1}>Heading</Box>
    </Typography>
    <Grid container spacing={3 as GridSpacing}>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <TextField
        label="MyTextField"
        InputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
        value={props.event.fromAction}
        fullWidth
        />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <TextField
        label="AnotherTextField"
        InputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
        value={props.event.request.sourceComponent}
        fullWidth
        />
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
</React.Fragment>
...
```

Has anyone managed to changed the `TextField` component's text to be styled as a Typography *caption* variant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  inputRoot: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(12),
    letterSpacing: "0.03333em",
    lineHeight: 1.66
  }
}));
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        defaultValue="test"
        InputProps={{ className: classes.inputRoot }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit TextField caption styling]

Related question: [How change default typography class of a formcontrollabel - material-ui | React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674888/how-change-default-typography-class-of-a-formcontrollabel-material-ui-react/58697484#58697484)

Related Material-UI code for finding the style attributes for `caption` Typography: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.2/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createTypography.js#L73